# How do I get PEP 484 type hints for flask_sqlalchemy classes?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, type-hinting

How do I get PEP 484 type hints with the flask_sqlalchemy package? I see that there are [type hints for SQLAlchemy](https://github.com/dropbox/sqlalchemy-stubs) provided by a third party, but is it possible to hook these up for models and queries defined with flask_sqlalchemy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [Flask SQLAlchemy Stubs](https://github.com/ssfdust/flask-sqlalchemy-stubs) which you can add to your mypy config as follow as

```
[mypy]
plugins = flasksqlamypy
```

Flask SQLAlchemy specific code typing code can be placed inside `TYPE_CHECKING` constant.

Here is an example:

```
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from flask_sqlalchemy.model import Model

    BaseModel = db.make_declarative_base(Model)
else:
    BaseModel = db.Model

class User(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)

user = User(id=42, name=42)  # Error: Incompatible type for "name" of "User"
                             # (got "int", expected "Optional[str]")
user.id  # Inferred type is "int"
User.name  # Inferred type is "Column[Optional[str]]"
```

Answer (score 1):

if you would like get hints from `query` property from model, ie. `MyModel.query.all()` , try it:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import BaseQuery

class MyModel(SomeCustomBaseModel):
  __tablename__ = "some_table"

# some columns definitions 

query: BaseQuery # <- this typed attr will show sqlalchemy methods (all, first, one, ...) hints at least in VSCode
```